# nestedsortable dynamic item not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

I am using this nested sortable plugin [mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable) and the only issue I have so far is when I dynamically add an item to the "tree", I am not able to expand or collapse the item(s). I am just using the sample code so far, and adding to that.

How I am adding the items dynamically:

```
$('#new-button').on('click', function() {       
   var nextId = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('nextId');
   var $li = $("<li id=\"list_" + nextId + "\"><div><span class=\"disclose\"><span></span>          
   </span>New Item</div>");
   $li.addClass('mjs-nestedSortable-leaf');         
   $('ol.sortable').append($li);            
})
```

When I add these new items to the tree, they work just fine - I can move them throughout the tree, make them children, etc.
However, when I try to collapse a new item that I have made a parent - there is no response.

I am sure I just haven't added the correct event handler somewhere, but I can't fin where that is happening. I have even triggered a destroy() and _create() of the tree after I add the new item(s), hoping that would "re-configure" all the items again. However, no luck there.
Can anyone tell me how I can properly hook up these new dynamically created items so they will be treated as other items in the tree?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I always recommend is setting up a http://jsfiddle.net showing your error if possible to help make it easier for others to help you debug your situation.

Comment: yes, I thought about it, and I probably should have done that. However, at this point, I actually solved my issue. I will post my solution when I can (apparently I can't for 8 hours)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after 2 days of looking at this, I was able to solve the issue. It is funny - the code I had been looking for was directly above the new code that I had entered. (Right under my nose.) Thanks to the kind people here for introducing me to: [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event) - that greatly helped me to track down where the events were being created in the first place!

```
$('#new-button').on('click', function() {       
    var nextId = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('nextId');
    //Begin creating dynamic list item
   var $li = $("<li id=\"list_" + nextId + "\">");
   var $lidiv = $("<div></div>");
   var $disli = $("<span class=\"disclose\"><span></span></span>");
   $li.addClass('mjs-nestedSortable-leaf');

   //Assign event listener to newly created disclose span tag above
   $disli.on('click', function() {
       $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed').toggleClass('mjs-nestedSortable-expanded');
    });

    //Now actually start to append to DOM
    $lidiv.append($disli);
    $lidiv.append("New List Item " + nextId);
    $li.append($lidiv);
    $('ol.sortable').append($li);           
})
```

Hopefully, this will help someone.
Here is a [working copy](http://brianthews.com/nested-sortable-insert.html) in case you want to see it in action.