# nestedSortable newly added item does not move

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-plugins, nested-sortable

```
var menu = $("ol.menu").nestedSortable({
            handle: '.move',
            items: 'li',
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            opacity: 0.7,
            toleranceElement: '> i',
            connectWith: 'ol',
            isTree: true,
        }).disableSelection();

        $('#addMenu').on('click',function(){
            var text = $('#menuText').val();
            var link = encodeURIComponent($('#menuLink').val()); 
            if(text != '' && link !=''){
                var html = $('<li id="menu_'+(parseInt(menu.children.length)+2)+'" class="mjs-nestedSortable-leaf">')
                            .append($('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move">'),
                                    '&nbsp;'+text+' - '+link,
                                    $('<span class="remove-btn removeMenu">')
                                        .append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">'),
                                    $('<ol>')                                        
                            );
                menu.append($(html));
                menu.nestedSortable('refresh');
                console.log(menu.nestedSortable('toArray'));
                $('#menuText').val('');$('#menuLink').val('');
            }else{
                alert('Menü Başlığı ve link boş bırakılamaz!');
            }

        });
```

I already red whatever I could find. But nothing has changed. I am adding new item to the list but I am not able to move it inside the sortable container. The elements which come with page loading are fine, they are moveable. How to make it happen.

I red this -> [nestedsortable dynamic item not collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702566/nestedsortable-dynamic-item-not-collapsing)

I couldn't event make the func "nextId" works....

What I am missig.

Thansk

Answer (score 1):

i thinck this is your problem :
all code in document.ready work when page's loaded. but when u append something it's not working! simplest way is :

you should add some thing like this to your code :

```
<div id="addmenu" onclick="yourfunction()" > </div>
```

js :

```
 function yourfunction(){
        var text = $('#menuText').val();
        var link = encodeURIComponent($('#menuLink').val()); 
        if(text != '' && link !=''){
            var html = $('<li id="menu_'+(parseInt(menu.children.length)+2)+'" class="mjs-nestedSortable-leaf">')
                        .append($('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move">'),
                                '&nbsp;'+text+' - '+link,
                                $('<span class="remove-btn removeMenu">')
                                    .append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">'),
                                $('<ol>')                                        
                        );
            menu.append($(html));
            menu.nestedSortable('refresh');
            console.log(menu.nestedSortable('toArray'));
            $('#menuText').val('');$('#menuLink').val('');
        }else{
            alert('Menü Başlığı ve link boş bırakılamaz!');
        } }
```

Comment: I already didn't. I used the pure JQuery sortable plugin and it works correctly. But I need some nested sortable things.

Answer (score 0):

I am really stupid. I have just forgotten the class name "move" for handle in dynamic var html :(.. I solved now.